# dhtmlx gantt to combine timeline

Tags: timeline, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

The date is like:

- project 1-A  11:00-12:00
- project 1-B  13:00-15:00
- project 1-C  17:00-17:30

These three tasks are in the same project.

And I don't want them to be three individual timeline.

So how can I combine them as a object and visualize in a timeline?

Because there are break time between two tasks, so I can't just set 1100 as **start_time** and set 1730 as **end_time**.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 'split task' out of them,

Give these tasks a common parent and mark it as split as shown here https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__split_tasks.html
Then items will be displayed in the same row.

Here is a plunk http://next.plnkr.co/edit/E6O8iXyjQeGWt4fP?preview